# Given Paths Format is Not Supported (Visual Studio / Azure)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, path, azure-storage

When i click the download link it send me to a error page trying to debug it its telling me that my given paths format is not supported

In my controller class:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadBlob(string file, string extension)
    {
        string downloadPath = await repo.DownloadBlobAsync(file, extension);
        return Json(downloadPath);
    }
```

In My Blob Storage class:

```
        public async Task<string> DownloadBlobAsync (string file, string fileExtension)
    {
        _cloudBlobContainerx = _cloudBlobClientx.GetContainerReference(containerNamex);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainerx.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);

        var path = downloadPath + file + "." + fileExtension;
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            fileStream.Position = 1;
            //fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);

            return path;
        }
    }
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported

The source of the error :

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message. Also, tell us what happened when you debugged it? What values are being passed?

Comment: @NightOwl888 i tried debugging but it kept on saying path format is not supported

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could set a **break point** to check the value of **downloadPath** or '**path**' field.

[image]

I have created a simple demo to download  a blob file to a local folder path. It works fine. You could refer to.

```
string containerNamex = "container002";
string file = "MyTest"; //a blob file named MyTest.txt
string fileExtension = "txt";
string downloadPath = @"D:\MyBlob\";
CloudBlobClient  _cloudBlobClientx = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
_cloudBlobContainerx = _cloudBlobClientx.GetContainerReference(containerNamex);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainerx.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);
var path = downloadPath + file + "." + fileExtension;
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
     {
          fileStream.Position = 1;
          blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
          Console.WriteLine("success");
      }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: For local folder it is working. Problem is coming with azure blob file path. something like this https://testdatastorage.blob.core.windows.net/image/flower.jpg